# How can I find my Teamviewer ID via SSH?

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, teamviewer

So I tried doing this command

```
root@server:~#   teamviewer --info print version, status, id
 TeamViewer                      10.0.35002
 teamviewerd status              teamviewerd start/running
 TeamViewer ID: Try restarting the TeamViewer daemon (e.g. teamviewer --daemon restart)
```

but apparently it can't find my ID and I must restart the tv daemon, I do this but it still says the same thing?? Is there any way to get my Teamviewer ID without this? I also tried checking the logs but there's nothing in there that's a Teamviewer ID.

**My issue is different to others because there is no information in the log files that indicate a client ID whatsoever.**

Answer (score 0):

Please verify you are searching in the correct logfile.

```
/var/log/teamviewer/your_user/TeamViewer10_Logfile.log
```

most likely is the logfile where your id is entered into. (replace your_user and the teamviewer version if needed.)

```
grep "id=[0-9]*" TeamViewer10_Logfile.log
```

will give you that information.

Comment: There's no such directory as you indicated, the only one is /var/log/teamviewer/TeamViewer10_Logfile.log and when I run grep there are sporadic numbers but none of which are the client ID.